# Run cron job in non-silent mode?

Tags: cron, sqlplus

I created a simple linux script that essentially calls sqlplus and puts the results in variable X.  I then analyze X and determine whether or not I need to send out a syslog message.

The script works perfectly when I run it from the command line as "oracle"; however when I use crontab as "oracle" and add it to my job, X isn't getting filled.

I could be wrong, but I believe the issue is since cron runs things in silent mode, X isn't actually getting filled, but when I run it manually it is.

Here's my crontab -l result (as oracle):

```
0,30 * * * * /scripts/isOracleUp.sh syslog
```

Here's my full script:

```sh
#Created by: hatguy
#Created date: May 8, 2012
#File Attributes: Must be executable by "oracle"
#Description: This script is used to determine if Oracle is up
#  and running.  It does a simple select on dual to check this.    

DATE=`date`
USER=$(whoami)

if [ "$USER" != "oracle" ]; then
    #note: $0 is the full path of whatever script is being run.
    echo "You must run this as oracle.  Try \"su - oracle -c $0\" instead" 
    exit;
fi

X=`sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba'<<eof
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;
set linesize 1000;
select count(*) as count_col from dual;
EXIT;
eof`

#This COULD be more elegant.  The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out
#which hidden characters are getting fed into X, so instead what I did was
#check the string legth (26) and checked that COUNT_COL and 1 were where I 
#expected.
if [ ${#X} -eq 26  ] && [ ${X:1:10} = "COUNT_COL" ] && [ ${X:24:3} = "1" ] ; then
    echo "Connected"
    #log to a text file that we checked and confirmed connection
    if [ "$1" == "syslog" ]; then
        echo "$DATE: Connected" >> /scripts/log/isOracleUp.log
    fi
else
    echo "Not Connected"
    echo "Details: $X"
    if [ "$1" == "syslog" ]; then
        echo "Sending this to syslog"
        echo "==========================================================" >>             /scripts/log/isOracleUp.log
        echo "$DATE: Disconnected" >> /scripts/log/isOracleUp.log
        echo "Message from sqlplus: $X" >> /scripts/log/isOracleUp.log
        /scripts/sendMessageToSyslog.sh "PROD Oracle is DOWN!!!"
        /scripts/sendMessageToSyslog.sh "PROD Details: $X"
    fi
fi
```

Here's output when run as oracle from terminal:

```
Wed May  9 10:03:07 MDT 2012: Disconnected
Message from sqlplus: select count(*) as count_col from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Here's my log output when run through oracle's crontab job:

```
Wed May  9 11:00:04 MDT 2012: Disconnected
Message from sqlplus:
```

And to syslog:

```
PROD Details:
PROD Oracle is DOWN!!!
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm a new linux user and this is my first linux script.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I'm running Oracle Unbreakable Linux 5.7

Answer (score 1):

My Oracle db skills are pretty limited but dont you need to set ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME ?

Check these variables from the command lines and set these variables within cron and retry.

Comment: That was it, thanks.  In my script setting ORACLE_SID=<mysid> and ORACLE_HOME=<myhome> did the trick.  When running the script directly, these variables were already set, but as a cron job they were not.  Thanks for your response, I had just about given up!!